# Create post using rest api with html content

Tags: rest-api

I'm trying to create a wordpress post with html code in content for images but I have a problem.
For example my content looks like:

```
<p><img src="https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/1?s=52&amp;v=4" style="width: 52px;"><br></p>
```

But in Wordpress editor this same code is with slashes so it doesn't display.

```
<p><img src=\"https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/1?s=52&v=4\" style=\"width: 52px;\"><br></p>
```

Api call:

```
  $api_response = wp_remote_post( 'http://example.com/apiwp/wp-json/wp/v2/posts', array(
  'headers' => array(
    'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'admin:xxxx' )
  ),
  'body' => array(
    'title'   => $title,
    'content' => $text,
    'status' => 'publish',
    'format'   => 'standard'
  )
) );
```

Is there any fix for this problem?

Comment: Can you also post your REST API call??

Comment: Edited my post.

Comment: My god. Just discovered that wysiwyg editor (summernote) is the problem with slashes..