# Creating a WordPress Post via REST API - HTML or Markdown?

Tags: posts, html, rest-api, api, wp-api

**When creating a post using the WordPress REST API, should the post body content include HTML or should the post body content be written in Markdown language?** Or can it be either?

I'm looking to include simple HTML such as links, formatting (`<strong>` tags) and possibly images (hosted elsewhere, like for example `<img alt="Test example image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">`).

I've seen many examples just using plain text strings and I'd like to know how to tell the WordPress API that I want to create a new post with HTML content in the post body.

**Please could someone advise and offer some clarity?**

I've seen someone else have difficulty when using HTML for images and so I'm not sure - [Create post using rest api with html content](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/340199/create-post-using-rest-api-with-html-content)

If you need more information from me to best answer this please do let me know.

Really hope you can help! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress doesn't support Markdown without a plugin. The content should be HTML.

Comment: Thank you. So in theory the following code should work ok?
`$api_response = wp_remote_post( 'http://example.com/apiwp/wp-json/wp/v2/posts', array(
  'headers' => array(
    'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'admin:xxxx' )
  ),
  'body' => array(
    'title'   => $title,
    'content' => "<p><a href=\"https://www.google.com\">Here is a link to Google</a></p>",
    'status' => 'publish',
    'format'   => 'standard'
  )
) );`

Comment: Seems ok, but basic authentication is not supported without a plugin. You should just try it.

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to run it passed someone before trying. Thank you so much @Jacob